# Update from 18.04 fix loop

Tags: package-management

I am trying to fix an update problem.  I have tried apt-get upgrade and there are unmet dependencies with My-sql I can seem to fix.

```
   root@odroid2:~# version
   version: command not found
   root@odroid2:~# lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
   Release:        18.04
   Codename:       bionic
   root@odroid2:~# apt install update-manager-core
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it 
   is not going to be installed
   Recommends: mecab-ipadic-utf8 but it is not going to be installed
   update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:18.04.11.13) but 1:20.04.10.11 is 
   to be installed
   update-manager-core : Depends: python3-update-manager (= 1:20.04.10.11) but 
   1:18.04.11.13 is to be installed
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a 
   solution).
   root@odroid2:~#
```

Any ideas>

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install 20.04 packages onto an 18.04 system. Check your apt sources. Remove any wrong-release sources.

Comment: and also, what is the output from `apt --fix-broken install`? (please note that 18.04 is well out of date, and you'll need to upgrade to a "supported" version